# How to configure multiple apache virtual hosts on multiple ports?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, virtualhost, https

I have a server with one IP address. I want to run several virtual hosts in an Apache 2.2. And I want all virtual hosts to be accessible on port 80 (plain http), 8000 (plain http) and 443 (ssl).

For example, I have two virtual hosts a.foo.com and b.foo.com. I want the following url to be accessible: http://a.foo.com, http://a.foo.com:8000, https://a.foo.com, http://b.foo.com, http://b.foo.com:8000 and https://b.foo.com. The virtual host a.foo.com should have the same content on all ports.

Here is my failed attempt. I haven't come to the SSL yet. I can't even figure out just the two plain http ports.

```
Listen 80
Listen 8000
NameVirtualHost *

<VirtualHost *>
ServerName a.foo.com
DocumentRoot /www/a
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
ServerName b.foo.com
DocumentRoot /www/b
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What sort of errors are you getting?

Comment: As far as I can see, you are just missing the `ServerName b.foo.com` to make things a little different.  But, as NickW stated, knowing the errors are the best way to find the solution.

Comment: @fboaventura, Opps, I made a typo in my question. I have corrected it. My config file doesn't have that typo.

Comment: @NickW, I should have mentioned it. Good you asked. The error is "You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port".

Comment: @WuYongzheng what errors are you getting?  I've made this same configuration at my machine and it just worked.

Comment: @fboaventura, As I answered to @NickW, the error is `You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port`. `httpd -S` reports `mixing * ports and non-* ports with a NameVirtualHost address is not supported, proceeding with undefined results`. I have fixed it by disabling SSL. However, I still can't make it work with SSL.

Answer (score 2):

It should be something like the following

```
Listen *:80
Listen *:8080

NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:8080

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName a.foo.com
   DocumentRoot /www/a
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
   ServerName a.foo.com
   DocumentRoot /www/a
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

For each virtual host you need to include the port also, say "VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:8080"

please refer http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: Does that mean I need to duplicate the <VirtualHost>...</VirtualHost> three times for both a.foo.com and b.foo.com?

Comment: Yes, you will need different configuration options for the https enabled hosts..